# xml: how to join a variable to the xml reponse

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My xml response:

```
<item>
<title geoid="1198">District of Columbia</title>
<description cong_dist="Delegate District (at Large) 98">DC - Delegate District (at Large) 98 <br/> No of Incidents: 1436</description>
<latitude>38.8933115</latitude>
<longitude>-77.0146475</longitude>
</item>
```

AND i have to add  a variable in it.,

that variable contain another xml reponse:

```
 var polygon=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("georss:polygon");

<georss:polygon>38.934311 -77.1199 38.939834989364 -77.112868886998 38.94641 -77.1045 38.94891 -77.1007 38.95651 -77.0915 38.960871062931 -77.085827416011 38.967245703105 -77.07753570311 -77.015598 38.97441 -77.013798 38.97011 -77.00829238.967245703105 -77.077535703105 38.960871062931 -77.085827416011 38.95651 -77.0915 38.94891 -77.1007 38.94641 -77.1045 38.939834989364 -77.112868886998 38.934311 -77.1199</georss:polygon>
```

i stored these values a variable as `polygon`.

so i have to join these values `polygon`  in the item tag.

how i have to od this??

Comment: Well first of all you need to show that `polygon` variable. Also you should tell what your concrete problem is. Where do you hit the roadblock?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($response_xml);
$sxe->addChild("polygon", $polygon);
$sxe->saveXML("new_updated.xml");
//echo $sxe->asXML();
```

If response XML file is on Disk:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file("response.xml");
```